# java objectmapper readvalue reading wrong string

Tags: java, json

I need to convert a certain `JSON` string to a Java object. I am using Jackson ObjectMapper for reading the `JSON`. The `JSON` String is something like this:-

`"{"emailId":"gmail@rajnikant.com","accessToken":"accTok"}4".`

When I am using `objectMapper.readValue()` for reading the `JSON` string to a specific destination class, it should throw an exception because of the `JSON` string being appended by 4. What should I do so that only valid JSON can be read and in other cases it will throw an exception?

Comment: Just remove the trailing *4* at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

To Jackson, GSON and others, a JSON string with some characters appended after the last `}` is valid JSON as long as what is contained between the `{}` is valid JSON.

As stated by a member of FasterXML (Jackson) team:

> Yes. This is by design. If you want to catch such problems, you need to construct `JsonParser`, advance it manually. Existence of multiple root-level values is not considered a validity problem.

Reference: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/726

So if you need to enforce "clean" JSON you'll have to extend the default parser with your own functionality. However, IMO if it's OK to the default parser it should be OK to you too (unless we're dealing with some inter-language incompatibility scenario here).